# MEF + WPF + MVVM: Where should AggregateCatalog reside?

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I'm taking my first crack at using MEF, but I can't seem to determine where I should create my `AggregateCatalog` and `CompositionContainer`. I have found many examples showing what the code should be:

```
var moduleCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()), 
    new DirectoryCatalog(moduleDir));
var container = new CompositionContainer(moduleCatalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

But now I just need to know where to put it. Should it go:

1. in `App.xaml.cs`
2. in `MainWindow.xaml`
3. or in one of my ViewModels.

**Edit:** Should have googled just a little longer, I think I found what I was looking for.

[Hosting MEF within application and libraries.](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/01/15/hosting-mef-within-your-applications/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this, [Hosting MEF within application and libraries](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/01/15/hosting-mef-within-your-applications/), I decided that the composition of `MEF` can go in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [Import]
    public Window TheMainWindow { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var moduleCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(App).Assembly), 
            new DirectoryCatalog(moduleDir));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(moduleCatalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        base.MainWindow = TheMainWindow;
        TheMainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

- `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` should be removed from `App.xaml`
- You will need to create a property for your main window, `import` it, and set `base.MainWindow` to it.